# VS Community Edition 2017: Add - > New Project is disabled

Tags: visual-studio

Using VS Community Edition 2017, I opened the solution file but "New Project" feature is disabled under Right click on Project-> Selecting "Add" --> "New Project". 
Please guide me how it can be resolve.

Comment: Is the solution running? Is the solution file locked/readonly?

Comment: Click on the *solution* node, not the project. You can't add a project to a project. This has nothing to do with the version or edition. The option was never available at the project level

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Would you even see that menu item if you right click on a project node? Question implies the option is disabled, not that it's not there.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. Kill the execution of the solution and then the option to add new projects to the solution is enabled again.